# Copy PostgreSQL database from a remote server

Tags: postgresql

When I was using MySQL, I could run a command that would SSH into my server and copy the database to my local machine.

```
ssh -t remoteserver 'mysqldump --compress -u dbuser --password="password" db_name' | /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root --password="password" local_db_name
```

How can I do the same thing with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the DB server takes database connections from your host (usually on port 5432), then you don't need to use SSH.  In this case, you need to do the following:

```
pg_dump -h your_db_host -U db_user -C db_name | psql -h localhost -d local_db_name -U local_db_user
```

If you can only connect to your database from the host itself, you have to add the SSH logic from your MySQL example.

With `-C`, you will get a `CREATE DATABASE` command in the beginning of the dump so you don't have to create it yourself.  The above command will ask for a password twice unless you store these in a [.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file (assuming you are on linux/Unix).  Also, the local connection may be different if your DB doesn't listen on TCP (in this case just omit the `-h localhost` part).

For further details and options, see [pg_dump documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html).

Comment: means you need to have the same password on both servers, right?

Comment: @FlorianHeigl No.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future: Enter the password for the first (remote) DB, press enter, type the password for your localhost DB user, press enter. The fact that it prompted for both passwords (and that UNIX never shows passwords as you tye them) confused me as well.